# How can I get this jQuery script working on WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slideshow

This is a slideshow directly added to a page in WordPress. I've added the stylesheet, the script, the slideshow itself and the script which executes the slider function but I just cannot get it in motion.

This is the code of the page:

```
        //PHP functions
        wp_enqueue_style('slideshow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slideshow.css', false, '1.1', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cslider.js', array ('jquery'), 1.1, true);

        <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>1. Easy management</h2>
                <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>

                <div class="da-info"></div>
                <div class="da-img da-bg1"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>2. Revolution</h2>
                <p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>

                <div class="da-info"></div>
                <div class="da-img da-bg2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>3. Warm welcome</h2>
                <p>When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane.</p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>

                <div class="da-info"></div>
                <div class="da-img da-bg3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>4. Quality Control</h2>
                <p>Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>

                <div class="da-info"></div>
                <div class="da-img da-bg4"></div>
            </div>

            <nav class="da-arrows">
                <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery('#da-slider').cslider({
                    autoplay    : true,
                    bgincrement : 450
                });
            });
        </script>
```

And here is the [cslider's link](http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/js/jquery.cslider.js)

Comment: Please provide any demo link.

Comment: Appreciate it might be hard to give a full demo as it's a wordpress build. Few things that stand out to me: Does get_stylesheet_directory_uri() give you the right directory (i.e. are you seeing the correct files in Chrome Dev tools and not getting any 404 errors). Are the file version names right/needed? You seem to be looking for file versions 1.1 of both the css and js - is that correct? One of those is being passed as a string ('1.1') the other as a number (1.1), but I'm not sure that matters.

Comment: Check your version of jquery

Comment: Did you load `Modernizr` somewhere in your code? Because this slider uses `Modernizer` internaly and I got an error `Modernizr is not defined`. Maybe you sould put it like dependency in `wp_enqueue` function?

Comment: @pgk You are right, the problem was the Modernizr script missed, now it's working!! Thank you so much!! I have to pay more attention to Chrome Dev Tools. @ Paul Thomas GC I just copied&pasted that functions, in fact I don't use versions, I will dig deeply in the usage

Comment: Hi @pgk can you convert your comment in an answer? So you can receive the proper credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load `Modernizer` library before `cslider` because slider uses `Modernizer` internally. Maybe the best way is to pass `Modernizer` as dependency when include `cslider` with `wp_enqueue_script()` function.

Answer (score 0):

@pgk You are right, the problem was the Modernizr script missed, now it's working!! Thank you so much!! I have to pay more attention to Chrome Dev Tools...

Comment: Hello jos3m, maybe you can bring @pgk to convert his comment into an answer, this way he'll recieve proper credit, if not please check this answer as accepted for proper closure.

Comment: Hi Clemens, sorry for my ignorance, but how can I do that?

Comment: Ask him if he can convert it, he just has to answer instead of comment, and you accept a anywer by clicking the check icon.

Comment: @Clemens Himmer,@jos3m thank you for the proposal, I will post my comment as answer.